# unlock Watch support with in app purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-watch

I'm building a photo editing app for iOS which will have watch support too, I want to keep it free because there are many photo editing apps already so would apple decline my app if I add in app purchase where it unlocks the watch support? Definitely not programming question but as watch is the new platform iam/many others are unaware of this.

Comment: If I am asking this question in Wrong place link me to correct place to ask this question .

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control the availability of your Watch app. It's just included with the main iOS app. You might be able to get away with charging IAP for specific Watch features, but that's it.